# execute a javascript code inside a json object?

Tags: javascript, json, eval

is there  away?

so something like:

```
{ key1 : "val1", key2: "val2", some_code: "document.getElementById("someid").innerHTML='test';" }
```

So some_code would be executed without any user intervention?

Comment: As below, yes you could. However, it's best avoided. If you're providing this to a 3rd party is should get blocked.

Answer (score 4):

No.

First of all, your example isn't valid JSON. Try it out at [JSON validator](http://www.jsonlint.com/).

Second of all, JSON is a data exchange standard and when properly parsed, any text that inside of it that is some code will not be executed.

Read on [JSON security issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json#Security_issues).

Rule of thumb: don't use JavaScript `eval` function, rather use a ready made parser such as Douglas Crockford's [JSON evaluator](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Comment: okay thanks guys - i think id probaly stick to that - json as data and no possible way to "self execute" a json object.

Answer (score 3):

This would not be JSON anymore. But you can post-process the parsed JSON:

```
json.some_code = eval(json.some_code);
```

However this may be dangerous (script injection, etc).

So, if you can, do this instead:

```
json = { key1 : "val1", key2: "val2", elem: "someid", html:"test" };
document.getElementById(json.elem).innerHTML=json.html;
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, first you need to escape the double-quotes:

```
{ key1 : "val1", key2: "val2", some_code: "document.getElementById(\"someid\").innerHTML='test';" }
```

(Or use single-quotes.)

If you want to evaluate the `some_code` field as a script, it's as simple as passing it to eval:

```
eval(obj.some_code);
```

This is, of course, very hazardous unless you have absolute control over the contents of `some_code`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do that, yes, for example by doing this :

```
{
  "functionName": function() {
    alert('Hello!');
  }()
}
```

However, that would not be valid JSON anymore. JSON does not accept functions.

Comment: hmm - a little difficult to construct and pass that structure from a backend server to the client browser eh?